# Sails.js Passport Authentication with JWTs

Tags: javascript, sails.js, passport.js

I have a Sails.js web API with an Angular (4.3) front end. Angular is sending requests with a Bearer token set in the headers, and I've confirmed that that part is working as expected.

I've installed `passport` and `passport-jwt` in my project. Here's my `sails/config/passport.js` file:

```
const JWT_STRATEGY_CONFIG = {
    secretOrKey: SECRET,
    issuer: ISSUER,
    audience: AUDIENCE,
    passReqToCallback: true,
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    algorithms: ['HS256', 'HS384']
};

function _onJwtStrategyAuth(payload, next) {
    // Got this part from a tutorial
    // https://ericswann.wordpress.com/2015/04/24/nozus-js-1-intro-to-sails-with-passport-and-jwt-json-web-token-auth/
    // unfortunately, it was written 2 1/2 years ago :/
    const user = payload.user;
    return next(null, user, {});
}

passport.use(new JwtStrategy(JWT_STRATEGY_CONFIG, _onJwtStrategyAuth));
```

As I said above, in the `_onJwtStrategyAuth` function, I got that function [from a tutorial](https://ericswann.wordpress.com/2015/04/24/nozus-js-1-intro-to-sails-with-passport-and-jwt-json-web-token-auth/) that's a couple years old. The thing is, even when I do nothing in that verify function, it doesn't change the result in my `authenticate` function:

```
passport.authenticate('jwt', (error, user, done) => {
    if (error || !user) {
        return res.forbidden();
    }
    return next();
})(req, res);
```

In that authenticate function, the error is always null, user is false, and done is an object that seems to be the error.

I am at a loss as to where I should go from here. I need to take the token in the headers, confirm that it's valid, and then allow people to get information from my API.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Im here to say that I have a solution for you! But I will write it up on friday, but it will be very complete.

Comment: @paulogdm another friday has passed :)

Comment: Inbox remembered me but Im really busy (never been this busy before).
I will be free to write it up on christmas week only =,(